# Слово "мухлевать"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а что за слово "мухлевать" (значение его я знаю, меня интересует происхождение)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из идиша через блатную феню.
//---
Происходит от нем. (арго) moheln «метить карты» (откуда нов.-в.-н. mogeln «плутовать, надувать»); от др.-еврейск. mâhal «подрезать; разбавлять вино». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.
(Вики)